# Azure Pipeline YML running template twice when separate bash commands are on different indents

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines-yaml

Here is a sample template with my problem

```
- template: my_template.yml
    parameters:
      build_steps:
      - bash: |
        "this is my bash stuff that I see dupped"
      displaymame: Install pkg
      workingDirectory: $(TempDir)
- bash: |
    "I do not see this dupped"
  displaymame: Doing more stuff
  workingDirectory: $(TempDir2)
```

Because I do not define another template above the second bash, it seems to run my_template.yml twice. So in my azure pipeline I see everything in my_template.yaml twice as well as `Install pkg` twice. But I do only see `Doing more stuff` once. But if I remove the second bash, my_template.yml is only run once.

Is there a way to run the second bash independent of a template without causing the most recent template to repeat?

I have run multiple different yaml combinations to see if I can get the template to not run twice, but I haven't been able to try anything that works.

Comment: [YML](https://fdik.org/yml/) is not the same as [YAML](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html) and the recommended extension for YAML files has been `.yaml` at least since Sep 2006.

Comment: You could try moving the second bash step outside of the template and into the steps section of your YAML file.